# How do I correct an error in DiffBind Program?

Tags: r

I'm running a diffbind program starting with this code:

```
library(rtracklayer)
library(DiffBind)
setwd('/Volumes/DEVBIO-21/Zorn-Genomics/TcfBcat_2022/Diffbind/TCF')
#samples <- read.csv("WTKO_Differential.csv")
#names(samples)
#samples
sox17 <- dba(sampleSheet = "TCF7Metadata.csv")
```

but when I get to this point, it generates the following error:

```
WT1 TCF7 D0 WT  1 narrow
WT2 TCF7 D0 WT  2 narrow
WT3 TCF7 D1 WT  1 narrow
WT4 TCF7 D1 WT  2 narrow
WT5 TCF7 D3 WT  1 narrow
WT6 TCF7 D3 WT  2 narrow
WT7 TCF7 PM WT  1 narrow
WT8 TCF7 PM WT  2 narrow
WT9 TCF7 NMP WT  1 narrow
WT10 TCF7 NMP WT  2 narrow
Error in mergeScores(merged, def, peakset, TRUE) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].
In addition: Warning message:
Removed white space from D1TCF7_Rep1.bam in column bamReads (row 3)
```

Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The files were corrupted. Never mind!